# the program freezes when i try to close close rs232 port

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, port

I have written a C# Windows-forms program that reads a weight-value from an RS-232 port.

Here is my program:

```
try { Brate = Convert.ToInt32(MyParam._BOUD1); }
catch { Brate = 9600; }
port = new SerialPort(MyParam._COM1, Brate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
port.DtrEnable = true;
port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

if (port.IsOpen == false)
{
    try
    {
       port.Open();
       port.DiscardOutBuffer();
    }
    catch (Exception oex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(oex.ToString());
    }
}

private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DoUpdate));
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  }
 }

private void DoUpdate(object s, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
     lblMSG2.Text = port.ReadLine().ToString();
     port.DiscardInBuffer();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    lblMSG2.Text = ex.ToString();
  }
}
```

This program is working excellently, except for when I try and close the form in order to open another form.

Here is how I close the serial-port:

```
if (port.IsOpen == true)
{
  port.DataReceived -= new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
  try
  {
     port.Close();
     port.DiscardOutBuffer();
  }
  catch (Exception oex)
  {
     MessageBox.Show(oex.ToString());
  }
}
```

My program hangs, and I can't do anything except for quit the program and restart it.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I tried everything suggested here

```
if (port.IsOpen == true)
{
  //port.DataReceived -= new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
  try
  {
    //port.Dispose();
    // port.DiscardOutBuffer();
    // port = null;
       port.Close();
   }
   catch (Exception oex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(oex.ToString());
   }
}
```

but still program hangs, and I can't do anything except for quit the program and restart it.

its stuck in this line: `port.Close();`

Comment: In which line does your code freeze?

Comment: I don't know this specific class, but perhaps you should call DiscardOutBuffer() before Close()?

Comment: Closing may lock up port.  I would try port = null;

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've updated the question

Comment: Hey have you solved this problem? I'm facing the same problem now. The code hangs while attempting to close connection.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're declaring a `new` event handler at the same time that you're trying to un-subscribe your existing handler.

Remove the code where it says:

```
port.DataReceived -= new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
```

This is most likely what's causing your hang-up. You don't need to have that code in there at all, because once you close the port you won't receive any new data anyways. Additionally, you should simplify what you're doing when you try to close the port. Change the code where you close the port to:

```
try
{
    if(port.IsOpen)
    {
        port.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception oex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(oex.ToString());
}
```

Given that all you're doing is using a simple event handler to receive some data over the port, the above code-block is all you really need to do to close out the port.

Comment: @developerdev okay, well what I think you should do next is get rid of the part where you discard the in-and-out buffers. Try that and let us know how it works.